# how to format drive with 32KB cluster

Tags: c#

I am not a C# programer but I need to format drive with 32KB cluster using C#. I found "Format method of the Win32_Volume class" but when I am trying to format drive I always get an error 15 (Cluster size is too small). This is my code:

```
    public static int DriveFormatting(string driveLetter)
    {
        string FileSystem = "FAT32", Label = "";
        Boolean QuickFormat = true, EnableCompression = false;
        UInt32 ClusterSize = 32;
        int result = -1;

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = '"+ driveLetter +"'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach(ManagementObject management in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Formating disk " + driveLetter + "...");
            result = Convert.ToInt32(management.InvokeMethod("Format", new object[] { FileSystem, QuickFormat, ClusterSize, Label, EnableCompression }));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to erase the drive and reformat.

Comment: `UInt32 ClusterSize = 32;` <-- This is 32 bytes, not 32 kb. `32 * 1024`

Comment: Thanks, it was my inattention